# Which library should i use for face Tracking for captured image?

Tags: iphone, opencv

I am creating one application with face processing. How may i create face animation?
Is there any library which i can use?
How to face track once capturing image of face?
Please help me

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware there is no completely free library to track facial expressions - which i think is what you need to produce aniamtion.

However, there is a commerical library for iOS (and other platforms) here: http://www.image-metrics.com/livedriver/overview/

This is available under a trial license and also a free educational licence.  I believe it will do what you want.

Your other option is to develop you own facial feature tracking system using something like OpenCV: http://opencv.org/
Thats going to be a challenge though.

Answer (score 0):

Face detection is already included in CoreImage (CI), see

http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/22/ios-5-face-detection-with-core-image/

If you want face recognition, you have to do something on your own, but there are some tutorials available - most of them using OpenCV.

Comment: That's correct but i want me to develop like capture 2D image convert into 3D. so i can move left and right. also require to lips should be having motion of speaking.

Comment: well then good luck. companies spend millions to develop such software - I am not aware of any good solution yet :)